# Angular OrderBy property of first item in child array

Tags: angularjs

I have the following JSON

```
{
    "item": { 
        "id": 1
        "owners": [
            {
                "name": "bob"
            }
            {
                "name": "jane"
            }
        ]
    }
    "item": { 
        "id": 2
        "owners": [
            {
                "name": "jim"
            }
            {
                "name": "mary"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I am trying to sort by the first owner so something like...

```
$scope.predicate = 'item.owners[0].name';
```

```
<div class="row item-row" ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:predicate:reverse"></div>
```

This doesn't seem to work though, is there a right way to do this?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you want to orderBy key "name" or by value "jim"?

Comment: By the value of name so 'jim' and 'bob'

Comment: Sorry let me improve the JSON it will make more sense. Does that make a little more sense? So I want to sort by the name of the very first owner every time.

Comment: What about `tails` array? anyway, you are trying to order by `'item.owners[0].name'`, like a string, it should be a value, so change `$scope.predicate = 'item.owners[0].name';` to `$scope.predicate = item.owners[0].name;`

Comment: Sorry tails == items I forgot to obfuscate :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the "predicate" is evaluated in the context of each `tail`, it should look like this: `owners[0].name`.

E.g.:

```
<div ng-repeat="tail in tails | orderBy:predicate:reverse">

$scope.predicate = 'owners[0].name';
$scope.reverse   = false;   // or true
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/Lxt47/)**.

Comment: Looks right I will 2x check in my local and give you the check thanks!